# Consumer<T> mapped Class<T> in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, java-8, type-safety

I want to create an `IdentityHashMap<Class<T>, Consumer<T>>`. Basically, I want to map a type with a method saying what to do with this type.

I want to dynamically be able to say with objects X, execute Y. I can do

```
private IdentityHashMap<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> interceptor = new IdentityHashMap<>();
```

but it sucks because then I have to cast the object in the lamba when using it.

Example:

```
interceptor.put(Train.class, train -> {
    System.out.println(((Train)train).getSpeed());
});
```

What I would like to do is

```
private <T> IdentityHashMap<Class<T>, Consumer<T>> interceptor = new IdentityHashMap<>();
```

But it doesn't seem to be allowed. Is there a way to do this ? What is the best workaround to map types with a method for this type ?

Comment: This is a sidelight, but note that `java.lang.Class` defines equality as identity, so there's no need to use `IdentityHashMap` here.

Comment: @ruakh There's no need to use `HashMap` either. What would it bring to have 2 extra `equals` call when comparing ?

Comment: Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html. You should only use `IdentityHashMap` when you specifically need it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is essentially just like the [type-safe heterogeneous container described by Joshua Bloch](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8), except you can't use the `Class` to cast the result.

Weirdly, I can't find a great example existing on SO, so here is one:

```
package mcve;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

class ClassToConsumerMap {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> map =
        new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Consumer<? super T> put(Class<T> key, Consumer<? super T> c) {
        return (Consumer<? super T>) map.put(key, c);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Consumer<? super T> get(Class<T> key) {
        return (Consumer<? super T>) map.get(key);
    }
}
```

That's type-safe, because the relation between keys and values is enforced by the signature of the `put` method.

One annoying thing about the limitations of Java's generics is that one of these containers can't be written for a generic value type, because there's no way to do e.g.:

```
class ClassToGenericValueMap<V> {
    ...
    public <T> V<T> put(Class<T> key, V<T> val) {...}
    public <T> V<T> get(Class<T> key) {...}
}
```

Other notes:

- I would use a regular `HashMap` or a `LinkedHashMap` for this. `HashMap` is better maintained and has many optimizations that `IdentityHashMap` doesn't have.
- If it's necessary to use generic types, like `Consumer<List<String>>`, then you need to use something like Guava [`TypeToken`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) as the key, because `Class` can only represent the erasure of a type.
- Guava has a [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) for when you need a `Map<Class<T>, T>`.

Sometimes people want to do something like this, with a class-to-consumer map:

```
public <T> void accept(T obj) {
   Consumer<? super T> c = get(obj.getClass());
   if (c != null)
       c.accept(obj);
}
```

That is, given any object, find the consumer in the map bound to that object's class and pass the object to the consumer's `accept` method.

That example won't compile, though, because `getClass()` is actually specified to return a `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `|T|` means the *erasure* of `T`. (See [JLS §4.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2).) In the above example, the erasure of `T` is `Object`, so `obj.getClass()` returns a plain `Class<?>`.

This issue can be solved with a [capturing helper method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html):

```
public void accept(Object obj) {
    accept(obj.getClass(), obj);
}
private <T> void accept(Class<T> key, Object obj) {
    Consumer<? super T> c = get(key);
    if (c != null)
        c.accept(key.cast(obj));
}
```

Also, if you want a modified version of `get` which returns any applicable consumer, you could use something like this:

```
public <T> Consumer<? super T> findApplicable(Class<T> key) {
    Consumer<? super T> c = get(key);
    if (c == null) {
        for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Consumer<? super T> value =
                    (Consumer<? super T>) e.getValue();
                c = value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

That lets us put general supertype consumers in the map, like this:

```
ctcm.put(Object.class, System.out::println);
```

And then retrieve with a subtype class:

```
Consumer<? super String> c = ctcm.findApplicable(String.class);
c.accept("hello world");
```

---

Here's a slightly more general example, this time using `UnaryOperator` and no bounded wildcards:

```
package mcve;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class ClassToUnaryOpMap {
    private final Map<Class<?>, UnaryOperator<?>> map =
        new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> UnaryOperator<T> put(Class<T> key, UnaryOperator<T> op) {
        return (UnaryOperator<T>) map.put(key, op);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> UnaryOperator<T> get(Class<T> key) {
        return (UnaryOperator<T>) map.get(key);
    }
}
```

[The `? super` bounded wildcard in the first example is specific to consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664), and I thought an example without wildcards might be easier to read.

Answer (score 8):

It *is* possible to implement this in a type-safe manner **without any unchecked cast**. The solution resides in wrapping the `Consumer<T>` into a more general `Consumer<Object>` that casts and then delegates to the original consumer:

```
public class ClassToConsumerMap {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<Object>> map = new IdentityHashMap<>();

    public <T> Consumer<? super T> put(Class<T> key, Consumer<? super T> c) {
        return map.put(key, o -> c.accept(key.cast(o)));
    }

    public <T> Consumer<? super T> get(Class<T> key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs, `get()` could also simply return a `Consumer<Object>`. This would be necessary if you only know the type at runtime, e.g.

```
classToConsumerMap.get(someObject.getClass()).accept(someObject);
```

<sub>I am pretty sure I saw this solution (or something similar) in a talk @ Devoxx Belgium 2016, possibly from Venkat Subramaniam, but I definitively cannot find it back…</sub>

Comment: This is really good, but it's not always a general solution. For example, it would be more difficult to use this pattern if we had a `Map<Class<T>, List<T>>`, or some other value we can't easily create adapters for.

Comment: @radiodef indeed, that will always be a case by case. I wish there was a cleaner way to do some generic typecasts without warning.

Answer (score 1):

I can just let the `IdentityHashMap` with the usual `Class<?>` and `Consumer<?>`

```
private IdentityHashMap<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> interceptor = new IdentityHashMap<>();
```

And then I wrap the put operation in a method. This method accepts a type and a consumer of the same generic.

```
public <T> void intercept(Class<T> type, Consumer<T> consumer)
{
    interceptor.put(type, consumer);
}
```

This lets me write

```
intercept(Train.class, train -> {
    System.out.println(train.getSpeed());
});
```