# Using nested generic types in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, hashmap

I am looking for a way to have a `Map` with generic types in the `Map`'s types and then retreive those using the key and the correct type. For example:

```
private final <T> Map<A<T>,B<T>> map = new HashMap<>();

public <T> B<T> getB(final A<T> a) {
  return map.get(a);
}
```

An example of using this would be:

```
final A<String> a = ...;
final B<String> b = getB(a);
```

Does this in any way exist or is there any workaround?

Edit: I know I can work around it by casting things, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way that does not require me to cast every value I retreive.

Comment: Just compile it.

Comment: Did you even try to code? This is already supported by `Map` interface

Comment: I have tried `protected <T> Map<OptionType<T>,OptionSet<T>> options;` which gave me `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`, that's why I'm asking if this is actually possible.

Comment: As for what I think you're asking, no it's not possible to declare a `Map` that way. Possibly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422685/consumert-mapped-classt-in-hashmap/44422954#44422954 for some examples of workarounds (possible duplicate?).

Comment: I have looked at that but those answers didn't really give me what I wanted.

Comment: Is that hard to read [API reference for Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) *before* asking this kind of question?

Comment: @zlakad which specific bit of that document do you think answers the question?

Comment: What's the problem with the answers at my link? The basic premise is going to be the same. There's no way to declare a `Map` this way, but sometimes we can do something like this with generic methods and (probably) casting.

Comment: @Radiodef I saw some casting things in the accepted answer. This may solve my problem but I am looking for a more elegant way that does not require me to cast, it it exists.

Comment: As it's private you could just use `A<?>` and `B<?>`. You have to cast the types at use-site.

Comment: @AndyTurner, for examle there is a link to `HashMap`, and then you can actually read about the constructor of that class.

Comment: private was just an example. See my edit though, I am looking for a more elegant way.

Comment: It would be easier to give a better answer then if you could edit your question to make it more clear what you want to do. You could write simple classes for `A` and `B` that show what you need to do with them, or use Java SE classes (e.g. `List<T>`, `Consumer<T>`, etc.) that perform a similar function. (For example, in the Q&A I linked to there was one solution posted that didn't use unchecked casting, but it depended on the specific fact that the question involved mapping `Class` to `Consumer`.)

Comment: @zlakad I'm not really talking about constructors. It might be a good idea if you read through my question a few times. Perhaps you will then understand what I need.

Comment: What I am trying to do is `protected <T> Map<OptionType<T>,OptionSet<T>> options;` as I pointed out before. What classes I use doesn't matter for my question though; the only thing I need is a way to link an OptionType<T> with an OptionSet<T> and get the Set from the Type without casting.

Comment: *It might be a good idea if you read through my question a few times.* If your question needs to be reread several times it would probably be a good idea to [edit] your question so it is more clear

Comment: @zlakad that tells you nothing, because the issue here is with the nature of type variables as a part of the language, not anything specifically related to the Map interface or its implementations.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I read your answer, and as a potentially consumer of OP's future library, I don't think I would be satisfied. IMHO, wild cards used in your way should be avoided. Why's so hard to think in OOP manner? Is it not possible to write something like this: `class A<T> {} class B<T> {}` and then `Map<A, B> map = new HashMap<>();`?

Comment: @zlakad I await your alternative answer with interest. But as a user of the library, the presence of a suppressed unchecked cast is neither visible nor troublesome, provided the code is written to enforce the type safety. I mean, you are going to trust (or prove otherwise) that the `get` method gets something, as opposed to wiping your hard drive, right? In the same way, you have to trust (or prove otherwise) that the code is type safe.

Comment: @AndyTurner, you edited your previous comment quickly. I have to re-read your answer and try to *prove otherwise*. With this I don't say you're wrong, but *maybe* wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't declare a map in this way. Basically, Java does not have an expressive-enough type system for this.

But luckily, the language provides an escape  hatch from using the type system, in the form of *casts*. Basically, casts are a way to provide type information that the compiler doesn't have; the onus is then on you, however, to make sure that it actually *is* type safe.

Firstly, declare the map with wildcard types:

```
private final Map<A<?>,B<?>> map;
```

Then, only put key/value pairs into the map which *do* meet the constraint:

```
<T> void put (A<T> key, B<T> value) {
  map.put(key, value);
}
```

And then cast when you get the element out again:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Safe
<T> B<T> get(A<T> key) {
  return (B<T>) map.get(key);
}
```

The point is that you can know more about the types than the compiler. Provided you take care to only put in safely-castable pairs, it is safe to cast them. (You also need to ensure that the `equals` method takes the type into account, so no `A<T>` equals `A<S>` unless `S == T`).

This is basically a "type-safe heterogeneous container", as described in *Effective Java* (Item 33 in 3rd Edition).

> I am wondering if there is a more elegant way that does not require me to cast every value I retreive.

For one thing, you aren't actually doing a cast in the `get` method at runtime: that's what an unchecked cast means.

For another, generics introduces *loads* of casts - basically generics is just a way to avoid inserting casts manually. So if there were a problem with the casts (such as performance), you'd already observe this in lots of places.

To paraphrase Kubrick: stop worrying, and love the cast.

Comment: This **is** a good answer, and I'll upvote it. The only thing what makes me a little bit nervous is when I see something like `A<?>` instead of `A<? super T>` for example. I still think that is better to know (in advance) what should be `K` and `V` in the `Map<K, V>`.

Answer (score -4):

Well, I was provoked to post this answer as a kind of view of OOP principles.

In the question stands `Map<A<T>,B<T>>`, so my approach would be to do something like this:

```
class A<T> {}
class B<T> {}

public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<A, B> map = new HashMap<>();
        A<Integer> a = new A<>(); //very safe
        B<String> b = new B<>(); //very safe

        map.put(a, b); //very safe

    }

}
```

I admit, there is an extra work, but...

Comment: Ow. My eyes. . .

Comment: @Priv, please, be free to down vote if you don't like it - I'll never delete this... Good luck.

Comment: You are actually doing the opposite of what I was looking for. `Map<A<T>,B<T>>` means `T` in `A` is the same as `T` in `B`, in other words, if you have `A<String>`, you must have `B<String>` too; I also mentioned in my post a method `<T> B<T> getB(A<T> a)`: if you pass an `A<String>`, you will always get a `B<String>` back.

Comment: @Priv, that's not true. Simple as that... You can declare `B<Integer>` or `B<WHATEVER>`...

Comment: ^That's what I asked. Simple as that.

Comment: It's not the `put` that OP is asking about, but rather the `get`: how to make that type-safe with heterogeneous types.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: @Radiodef, I know what is type erasure. Will we suggest to Java language developers to simply erase this as unnecessary feature while in compile time?

Comment: Why do you think raw types are an improvement over using wildcards? Why do you have comments which say `//very safe` all while violating the specific requirement in the question (which is enforced by Andy's example)?

Comment: @Radiodef, please, don't put the words in my mouth I've never spoken. I have just one question: what is the difference in this case: `<?>` and `<Object>`?

Comment: @Priv, why are you so angry (and rude, btw)? I'm not angry at all. I promised I won't delete this answer, since I think that you could chose a different approach to your problem. In my answer I **deliberately** declared classes A and B with a different types, just to show that the only thing you have to do is to declare these classes with the **same** type `<T>`. Andy provided the right answer if you're not able to do this.